# C++ type casting when passing argument by reference

Tags: c++, casting, reference, parameter-passing, reinterpret-cast

I have a function `foo` with an `int` parameter passed by reference. And I have a variable with `uint16_t` type. I use `reinterpret_cast` and here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>


void foo(int &bar) {
    std::cout << "bar = " << bar << std::endl;
    bar += 10;
}

int main() {
    uint16_t baz = 100;
    uint16_t qux = 200;
    foo(reinterpret_cast<int &>(baz));
    std::cout << "baz = " << baz << ", qux = " << qux << std::endl;
    foo(reinterpret_cast<int &>(qux));
    std::cout << "baz = " << baz << ", qux = " << qux << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
bar = 100
baz = 110, qux = 200
bar = 7209160
baz = 110, qux = 210
```

My questions are:

1. Why in the 2nd time calling `foo()`, it prints a wrong number, but variable `qux` is eventually correct?
2. What's the correct way to do a type casting when calling a function whose argument is passed by reference?

Comment: The correct way to do a type cast when calling a function whose argument is passed by reference is to not do it. Change the type of those two things to `int` and all will be well. `reinterpret_cast` is a big red flag; don't do it.

Comment: @Pete Becker is correct.  A reference is simply the address location of a variable with a specific type in memory.  Casting the reference doesn't change the underlying data type.  Either promote baz and qux to INT or overload the function foo for uint16_t

Answer (score 2):

1. In your function `foo`, `std::cout` is treating a `uint16_t` argument as an `int` so it is reading two extra bytes. 200 in decimal, the value of `qux` is 0x00C8 in hexadecimal. That big long decimal number 7209160 is 0x006E00C8 in hexadecimal. Do you see your `qux` value in that hex string? The leading part of that hex string is 0x006E which is in decimal 110, meaning that std::cout is probably also grabbing the `baz` variable off the stack when it reaches for your `qux` variable which is only of size uint16_t; it is looking for an int, which is twice that size. The variable is eventually correct because the second time it is passed to cout, it is being correctly treated as a uint16_t value.
2. The correct way to do type-casting in this scenario is to use `static_cast` as this cast will tell you if it can make a valid conversion between the two types. In this case, your compilation would fail. This is in contrast to `reinterpret_cast` which simply instructs the compiler to treat a sequence of bits as a different type, without any consideration given to type conversion.

Comment: That's a possible mechanism. But the behavior is undefined. And note that this explanation fails if the compiler lays out auto objects differently from the one you're using.

Comment: The first `bar` print can be `13107300`, which is what I am getting. So @PeteBecker is right, this is a possible explanation, but there's no reliability or gurantee that this is what will happen always. UB

Comment: Of course it is undefined and of course I am not making any guarantee that the output will be the same on every compiler. I am just explaining why std::cout probably displayed this particular number in this particular scenario. My compiler, clang, gets the exact same output.

Comment: I know, but just wanted to add this to the answer. Thanks, I learned something new :)

Comment: So why `static_cast` does not allow me to do type casting from `int &` to `uint16_t &`? It is normal to cast `int` to `uint16_t`, and sometimes `int *` to `uint16_t *`. Why this doesn't work for references? (@PeteBecker also mentioned this -- avoid type casting when passing arguments by references -- in comment of the question.)

Comment: @AlexanderZhang -- the reason that `static_cast` doesn't support this conversion is that the conversion is dangerous. You can do the conversion with the red-flag `reinterpret_cast` and, as you've seen, the resulting code produces nonsense.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang There is a difference between conversion from `int*` to `uint16_t*` and `uint16_t*` to `int*` on architectures that has 4 bytes long `int`s. You can get away with lying other function that you provide something smaller than it really is (but you will regret it, when someone will run your code on big-endian architecture). You've got bitten because you are lying that you are giving something bigger than you are really providing.

Answer (score 1):

every time the program has the same results? I translate the 200 and 7209160 to binary, and they are 11001000 and 11011100000000011001000. And they have same low 8 bits. Thus i guess whether it convert to type int has error. This can be verity to use int declare "quz".

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior (UB), even in the case `foo(reinterpret_cast<int &>(baz));` which seems to works (possible output of UB).

Simpler would be to remove cast and change `foo` to:

```
void foo(int bar);
```

If you cannot change `foo`, then, use intermediate variable:

```
uint16_t baz = 100;
uint16_t qux = 200;
int i = baz;
foo(i);
std::cout << "baz = " << baz << ", qux = " << qux << std::endl;
i = qux;
foo(i);
std::cout << "baz = " << baz << ", qux = " << qux << std::endl;
```